# PySpark / Mongodb Dataframe to Nested Collection

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Pandas dataframe in the following format.  Data has been pre-aggregated.

```
+---------------------------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|InterfaceName              |StartDate |StartHour|DocumentCount|TotalRowCount|
+---------------------------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|Interface_A                |2023-04-01|0        |5            |4384         |
|Interface_A                |2023-04-01|1        |58           |57168        |
|Interface_B                |2023-04-01|1        |1            |136          |
|Interface_C                |2023-04-01|1        |1            |131          |
|Interface_A                |2023-04-02|0        |58           |57168        |
|Interface_B                |2023-04-02|0        |1            |131          |
|Interface_C                |2023-04-02|0        |1            |136          |
|Interface_A                |2023-04-02|1        |2            |1657         |
|Interface_B                |2023-04-02|1        |2            |1539         |
|Interface_C                |2023-04-02|1        |2            |1657         |
+---------------------------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

Using PySpark, how can I transform the dataframe so that the schema appears as follows, then write to a structured collection in MongoDb?

```
root
 |-- StartDate: date (nullable = true)
 |-- StartHour: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- InterfaceSummary: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- InterfaceName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- DocumentCount: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- TotalRowCount: string (nullable = true)
```

Thanks in advance,

Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below implementation - 
(I have created the spark dataframe directly using the input data you've shared). But in order to explicitly create the spark dataframe from `pandas` dataframe you could use this code - 
`df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)`
Here `pdf` will be your `pandas` dataframe. 
)

**Input Data** -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("InterfaceName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("StartDate", StringType(), True),
    StructField("StartHour", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("DocumentCount", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("TotalRowCount", IntegerType(), True)
])

data = [
    ("Interface_A", "2023-04-01", 0, 5, 4384),
    ("Interface_A", "2023-04-01", 1, 58, 57168),
    ("Interface_B", "2023-04-01", 1, 1, 136),
    ("Interface_C", "2023-04-01", 1, 1, 131),
    ("Interface_A", "2023-04-02", 0, 58, 57168),
    ("Interface_B", "2023-04-02", 0, 1, 131),
    ("Interface_C", "2023-04-02", 0, 1, 136),
    ("Interface_A", "2023-04-02", 1, 2, 1657),
    ("Interface_B", "2023-04-02", 1, 2, 1539),
    ("Interface_C", "2023-04-02", 1, 2, 1657)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.show(truncate=False)

+-------------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|InterfaceName|StartDate |StartHour|DocumentCount|TotalRowCount|
+-------------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|Interface_A  |2023-04-01|0        |5            |4384         |
|Interface_A  |2023-04-01|1        |58           |57168        |
|Interface_B  |2023-04-01|1        |1            |136          |
|Interface_C  |2023-04-01|1        |1            |131          |
|Interface_A  |2023-04-02|0        |58           |57168        |
|Interface_B  |2023-04-02|0        |1            |131          |
|Interface_C  |2023-04-02|0        |1            |136          |
|Interface_A  |2023-04-02|1        |2            |1657         |
|Interface_B  |2023-04-02|1        |2            |1539         |
|Interface_C  |2023-04-02|1        |2            |1657         |
+-------------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Transformed Schema** -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1 = df.select(
                col("StartDate").cast("Date"),
                col("StartHour").cast("Integer"),
                struct(
                  col("InterfaceName"),
                  col("DocumentCount").cast("String").alias("DocumentCount"),
                  col("TotalRowCount").cast("String").alias("TotalRowCount")
                ).alias("InterfaceSummary")
)
df1.show(truncate=False)
df1.printSchema()

+----------+---------+------------------------+
|StartDate |StartHour|InterfaceSummary        |
+----------+---------+------------------------+
|2023-04-01|0        |{Interface_A, 5, 4384}  |
|2023-04-01|1        |{Interface_A, 58, 57168}|
|2023-04-01|1        |{Interface_B, 1, 136}   |
|2023-04-01|1        |{Interface_C, 1, 131}   |
|2023-04-02|0        |{Interface_A, 58, 57168}|
|2023-04-02|0        |{Interface_B, 1, 131}   |
|2023-04-02|0        |{Interface_C, 1, 136}   |
|2023-04-02|1        |{Interface_A, 2, 1657}  |
|2023-04-02|1        |{Interface_B, 2, 1539}  |
|2023-04-02|1        |{Interface_C, 2, 1657}  |
+----------+---------+------------------------+

root
 |-- StartDate: date (nullable = true)
 |-- StartHour: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- InterfaceSummary: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- InterfaceName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- DocumentCount: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- TotalRowCount: string (nullable = true)
```

Once you have the transformed dataframe created. You can write it to your target mongodb collection somewhat as below -

```
mongo_uri = "<mongodb>://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>.<collectionname>"
database_name = "<dbname>"
collection_name = "<collectionname>"

df.write.format("mongo") \
  .option("uri", mongo_uri) \
  .option("database", database_name) \
  .option("collection", collection_name) \
  .mode("append") \
  .save()
```

Comment: Thanks Dipanjan, that's perfect.  Is there a way to then group the output based on StartDate & StartHour?  For example, in MongoDb collection I would expect:

  {
    _id: ObjectId("642bd2876518624df40a82b4"),
    StartDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T13:00:00.000Z"),
    StartHour: 1,
    InterfaceSummary: [{
      InterfaceName: 'Interface_A',
      DocumentCount: '58',
      TotalRowCount: '57168'
    },{
      InterfaceName: 'Interface_B',
      DocumentCount: '1',
      TotalRowCount: '136',
  }] 
}

Comment: Ended up using collect_list:
df_docs = df_docs.groupBy(["StartDate","StartHour"]).agg(F.collect_list(struct(
    col("InterfaceName").alias("InterfaceName"), 
    col("DocumentCount").cast("Integer").alias("DocumentCount"),
    col("TotalRowCount").cast("Integer").alias("TotalRowCount"))).alias("InterfaceSummary"))

Comment: Yeah you could do that but you'll have to define the schema likewise